# Query records from same table not present in last 30 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called page loads with following columns

```
user_id
timestamp
country
city
```

The table has 37 million records with index on both columns

the timestamp ranges from 7/23 to 9/27

What I need to do is : For date range 8/24 to 9/27, count distinct users on each day that don't exist in the table with previous 30 days.

So for users in table that exist on 8/24, find count of distinct users who are not present in table between 7/23 and 8/23. The same needs to be done for each day between 8/24 to 9/27.

```
select
    count(distinct user_id)
from
    pageloads
where
    user_id not in (select user_id from pageloads where time between
'2015-07-24 00:00:00' and '2015-08-23 23:59:59')
and left(time,10) = '2015-08-24'
```

This approach is extremely slow because of not in clause and also runs for 1 day at a time.

Can someone help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
AND NOT EXIST ( select 1 from pageloads p1 where  p1.time between
'2015-07-24 00:00:00' and '2015-08-23 23:59:59' and p1.user_id = user_id)
```

NOT EXIST is very efficient as it stops to search when it finds 1 record. If there is no record then it will be discovered also immediatly. The index on user_id can be used too.

Answer (score 0):

IN clause is extremely slow if you have subquery in. Better use temporary table and join, it's much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some tests and i find my best solution. i did not now how often you will generate this report, but if you work with a new cumulated table i get the best result.

In this table you store the cumulated values per day / user and if you want to generate the report at the next day its only necessary to update the new table with the data from one day.

**The new table**

```
CREATE TABLE `pageload_cum` (
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `time` DATE,
  `quantity` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`time`),
  KEY `time` (`time`,`user_id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Fill the table**

This query will insert all data for the last 60 days, that will be used for a report starting from yesterday. if you start it tomorrow it will only generate
the missing day

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO pageload_cum
SELECT DISTINCT p.user_id ,
  DATE(p.`time`),
  SUM(1) AS quantity 
FROM pageloads p
WHERE
 DATE(p.`time`) NOT IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT p.time FROM pageload_cum p
 )
AND p.`time` > SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 61 DAY)
AND p.`time` < SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY DATE(p.`time`), p.user_id;
```

**Now the Report**

The report generates some columns that are only to understand the results. You can delete them if you are not using them. For one column "group_concat_max_len" it is necessary to set a variable to the size to hold the complete result. You can set it before the query or directly in your my.cnf.

```
SET  group_concat_max_len=16384;

SELECT
  DATE(p.`time`) checkdate,
  DATE(SUBDATE(`p`.`TIME`, INTERVAL 31 DAY)) AS hist_start,
  DATE(SUBDATE(`p`.`TIME`, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS hist_end,
   sum(1) AS cnt_user,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.user_id SEPARATOR ', ') user_not_hist
  FROM pageload_cum  p
  LEFT JOIN pageload_cum hist
    ON  `hist`.`TIME` BETWEEN DATE(SUBDATE(`p`.`TIME`, INTERVAL 31 DAY)) AND DATE(SUBDATE(`p`.`TIME`, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
    AND p.user_id = hist.user_id
  WHERE 
  hist.user_id IS NULL
 AND
   `p`.`TIME`  BETWEEN '2015-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-09-30 23:59:59' 
   GROUP BY DATE(`p`.`TIME`);
```

**The Result**

I have tested this query only with 10.000.000 rows in the pageload table and change some data for this result.

```
+------------+------------+------------+----------+--------------------------+
| checkdate  | hist_start | hist_end   | cnt_user | user_not_hist            |
+------------+------------+------------+----------+--------------------------+
| 2015-09-13 | 2015-08-13 | 2015-09-12 |        1 | 3333                     |
| 2015-09-27 | 2015-08-27 | 2015-09-26 |        4 | 4567, 5678, 12345, 31313 |
+------------+------------+------------+----------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.29 sec)
```

**The least**

It is not necessary to DELETE the hole table. You can remove only old data from days that you never use again like

```
DELETE FROM pageload_cum WHERE `time` < DATE(SUBDATE(now(), INTERVAL 100 DAY));
```

Please let me now if that the report you want.